# VMs on Hyper-V Host go into Saved State after Host reboots

Tags: hyper-v, server-message-block, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I have been noticing at times VMs on my Hyper-V Host are going into a Saved state after the host reboots. This means I have to manually start the VMs each time. Each VM is set to "Always start this virtual machine automatically" under the Automatic Start Action property, as well as "Save the virtual machine state" under Automatic Stop Action. Most of the VMs that are affected are Server 2012 R2. The Hyper-V host is on Server 2012 R2 and there is plenty of space and memory. We do use SMB Storage, so I'm not sure if the VMs on the host can't communicate to the storage which causes them to go into a saved state. Any suggestions as to what may be causing this?

-Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Most probably there are some resources (storage?) still missing by the time Hyper-V tries to start your VM's. Try to set a start up delay for your virtual machines (a couple of minutes after hypervisor goes up and running) and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, the problem may happen when a physical disk is not available.

As for logging you may find loads of Hyper-V related events under in Event Viewer > Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows, you could check if any error/warning.

And the problem only happens to server 2012R2? For a test, please shutdown that VM and copy it's VHD file then create new VM and attach that copied vhd to it .

Please start that the new VM to check if the issue still persists.